# Incomprehensible errors in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

This works:

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return Float(sum) / Float(numbers.count)
}
averageOf() // (not a number)
averageOf(42, 597, 12) // (217.0)
```

But this doesn't:

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return Float(sum / numbers.count)
}
averageOf()
averageOf(42, 597, 12)
```

It gives me this error on the `}` line:

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I stumbled upon [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150602/float-divison-and-casting-in-swift) with the same first and second snippets of code and the author apparently doesn't get the same errors.

Let's remove that cast:

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum / numbers.count
}
averageOf()
averageOf(42, 597, 12)
```

It gives me this error, on the division sign:

```
Cannot invoke '/' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue Int, Int)'
```

If I then change the return type of the function to `Int`:

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum / numbers.count
}
averageOf()
averageOf(42, 597, 12)
```

I get the same EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

If I cast only `numbers.count`:

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum / Float(numbers.count)
}
averageOf()
averageOf(42, 597, 12)
```

I get this error on the division sign:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue Int, $T5)'
```

I also get this error if I change the return type back to `Float`.

All of this makes no sense to me. Is it Xcode going postal, or have I missed something subtle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained, the problem in the second example is due to invoking `averageOf()` without arguments, which results in a division by zero. However, the first `averageOf()` works, again without arguments, why? Let me add a few more details.

In the first case you reported, you get no error and `averageOf()` works, because you are casting the two `Int` operands to `Float` before the division.
In the world of `Float` numbers, 0.0 is only an approximation of 0. If you try `0.0 / 0.0` in a Playground, you won't get an error as a result, the output, instead, will be `not a number`.

In the second case, however, you're trying to divide 0 by 0 before casting to `Float`. Therefore, we are still in the realm of `Int` numbers when the division is performed. The result is an error, due to a division by zero (no approximation involved here). If you try `0 / 0` in a Playground, you'll get an error.

All the other cases not explained by the `Int` vs `Float` behavior, are due to the fact that Swift requires to you explicitly cast between types, even when another language would let you cast the operands implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This error occures, because of your function-call `averageOf()`.
If you pass no values, to the variadic parameter `numbers` it creates an empty array.
It's `count` property therefore returns `0`. And you can't devide by `0`.
This is also the reason why it says `BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

If you remove `averageOf()` from your second code example it works.